# How to archive new build files in jenkins -pipeline script in groovy ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

trying to archive all the files into a zip file that is formed in the workspace in jenkins pipeline script. I tried using this

archiveArtifacts 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\pipeline CI_MS\workspace'

but error was shown as "file not found"

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to archive everything in the entire workspace? Hardcoding the path like that is a bad idea. The workspace moves, and if you are using a more recent version of Jenkins (that wasn't upgraded from an old version), you are probably not even looking in the right space.

Use this:

```
archiveArtifacts "${WORKSPACE}"
```

Add to the end of the path if you want to archive files in subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks actually what I want is to zip all the files each time a new build is created and archive it .

Comment: Then you will need to zip them in a shell and then archive the appropriate files.

Comment: Ummm... Google it. It depends on your OS, shell, exactly what you are trying to zip.